# Download speed vs SpeedTest results

Tags: networking, download, bandwidth, fiber

I'm currently subscribed to 500M fiber package with Asus AC68U Router and Asus PCE AC68 dual band network card. I'm connected on the 5ghz band and pinged over 250 Mbps download speed results on speedtest.net, but my direct downloads on movies are only achieving 50-200 kb/s, (I've achieved over 1Mb/s pre-fiber previously), any ideas?

Comment: You can't diagnose speed issues from a single speed test. There are multiple places in the local network that can create bottlenecks.  First step, plug laptop directly to the modem, bypassing local router and WIFI both. Once you have readings from multiple speedtest sites and have a good idea what you are getting add in the router but keep the connection wired, do all the speed tests over. Lastly add in wifi and re-test. THAT will give you an idea where your bottleneck is.

Comment: Keep in mind that your download speed depends on the server sending speed, as well as the transmission speed of all nodes inbetween and your receivind speed. You increased your receiving speed. When the server is under heavy load or far away from you than it doesnt matter how good your connection is. That's my big websites like facebook or wikipedia have servers all across the country

Answer (score 1):

You might have a fast download speed but you have to remember that that is not the only factor to count. You also have to count that the server you are downloading from has to serve multiple people and that its upload speed is whatever it can give you, as a single user, will be what you get.

In addition to that, speedtest employs multiple servers in different locations and will do the test on the closest one to you with the least amount of routers and gates along the way. The server you might be downloading from might be half way across the planet and that will cause a loss in data that will have to be re-transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are being throttled by your ISP. You mentioned downloading movies; I know for a fact that my ISP will throttle any p2p downloads (Linux ISOs, etc) if I use over a certain amount of transfer each month.

If it isn't p2p, bear in mind that servers may only allocate a certain amount of bandwidth to each client, to ensure one doesn't hog it all.